# Add image or icon set to asset catalog to be used with NSToolbarItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have a set of pixel perfect icons which I want to use on toolbar (NSToolbar) of my app. Toolbar is configurable thus I need to provide icons in four sizes: small, standard, small@2x, standard@2x.
I could not find any official information about the size of those icons, but unofficial information (confirmed by my tests) is the following:
 small is 24px, normal is 32px.

Thus I need to add four different images: 24x24px, 32x32px, 48x48px, 64x64px to my image set.

As for now I could not find a correct way for that.
I have tried a dozen of different methods but could not find one which preserves pixel perfect quality of all four images.

I believe, I can load right size of the image manually each time it has to be changed, but I am wondering if where is a correct way for that.

Does anyone has a good solution for that?

And yes, I clean build folder before each test.

Comment: Oleg, did you ever find out an answer to this?  I have the same exact question: how to add separate assets for the 24x24 1x/2x light/dark versions, plus the 32x32 1/x/2x light/dark versions.  Sure -- I can always add SEPARATE assets.  But how does NSToolbarItem know to look inside separate assets?

Comment: SMGreenfield, I believe where are no easy answer for this. I decided to disable standard size (32x32 and 64x64) on my toolbars and restrict them only to small size.

Comment: After working with Apple Developers, I've found that it works PERFECTLY to provide a singular 128 x 128 pixel image (one each for light mode and dark mode).  I was worried about the scaling, but I've looked at it carefully and it seems to be very accurate to the .png files we are using.  Now if I could only get NSToolbarItem's allowsDuplicatesInToolbar feature to work <g>...

Answer (score 0):

See the Apple Developer site Human Interface guidelines for formats and sizes. The requirements are different for the different devices, and quite detailed.

For a quick & dirty solution if you're not ready to ship and just want nice looking graphics for testing, I've found that one 512 x 512 pdf, labeled "image@2x" works pretty well. You need to set the

```
imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyDown
```

and Cocoa will take care of the rest. But it's definitely not ready for prime-time.

Comment: 1. A quote form Apple Documentation about the size of an image on a toolbar would be nice. Thanks.

2. Your "quick and dirty solution" is not does not meet my "pixel perfect" needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The NSToolbar.sizeModes are enum: small and regular. Small is 24x24 and regular is 32x32; additionally the retina options allow for @2x (48x48 and 64x64) and potentially @3x future-forward.

Apple documentation on these sizes can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/sizemode/small) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/sizemode/regular)

Make sure to use enum `Regular` not "`Standard`", which is undocumented.

Comment: This is great you gave the official references! Do you have any ideas on how to put all these pictures to the assets under the same name?